# Access two tables at a time in .net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-services

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [ID]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Phone]
    ,[Email]
    ,[AID]
    ,[Password]
    ,[Date/time]
    ,[IsVerify]
    ,[ProfilePicture]
FROM 
    [ChefODine].[dbo].[User]
```

This is my User table AID is the foreign Key of address table having following fields.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [ID]
    ,[Location]
    ,[LAT]
    ,[Lng]
FROM 
    [ChefODine].[dbo].[Address]
```

I want to add user address and other info in database through web service. i want that whenever user add his info the address will save in address table and AID will save in user table. This is my code Please guide me i am new in this.

```
[HttpPost]
public User Register([FromBody]User user)
{
    if (db.Users.Any(x => x.Email == user.Email))
        throw new Exception("Username \"" + user.Email + "\" is already taken");

    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return user;
}
```

Comment: can you also post the User and the Address class?

Comment: They have not any class they are entities

Comment: By the way, a better way to show the structure of a table (better than a `Select` statement) is the `Create Table` statement you get if you right click a table in SQL Server Management Studio and choose _"Script Table As -> Create To"_.  That way you will show the types as well as the names.  What database access mechanism are you using?  It looks like either Linq2SQL or Entity Framework

Comment: Its entity framework

Comment: the Entities from the database are mapped to a class in c#. Do you use Code First? for generating the entity framework layer?

Comment: @SergiuMuresan yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Specify the value before hitting into `SaveChanges` something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public User Register([FromBody]User user)
{
    if (db.Users.Any(x => x.Email == user.Email))
        throw new Exception("Username \"" + user.Email + "\" is already taken");
    user.Email  = "this is the Email from anywhere";
    user.AID = "This is your Aid Value";
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

     //If you want to save Address
   AddressEntity adr = new AddressEntity()
    adr.address = "This is your new address";
    db.Address.Add(adr);
    db.SaveChanges();


    return user;
}
```